# Midnight Commander: configure error: S-Lang library version 2.0 or newer not found

Tags: updates, midnight-commander, configure

Trying to update Midnight Commander to the latest version (4.8.23), I downloaded the corresponding tar.xz file from their website (http://ftp.midnight-commander.org/?C=N;O=D), extracted the files and issued `./configure`, but afterwards I get the error:

`configure: error: S-Lang library version 2.0 or newer not found`

However, the output of `sudo apt-get install libslang2` tells me I already have the newest version (2.3.1a-3ubuntu1) of that library.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem on Fedora. The solution I found was to install slang-devel package:

```
sudo dnf install slang-devel
```

Installing this package somehow fixes the configure error. The solution was found [here](http://r00ssyp.blogspot.com/2017/03/mc-centos7.html) (in Russian):

```
И вновь досадная ошибка:
configure: error: S-Lang library version 2.0 or newer not found
Исправляем установкой пакета:
# yum install  slang-devel
```

I believe there is a corresponding slang-devel package in Ubunu as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `libslang2-dev` was the package name in Ubuntu. I also had to install `libglib2.0-dev`, and then everything worked.